# Play video using desktop C# application

Tags: c#, video

I would like to play some videos (don't care about audio) in my application (C#). However, all video players I try to use looks like not available.

I'm am using Visual C# Express (don't know if there are any limitations concerning the libraries), and every time I try to add a reference to my project in order to play a video, it simply is not shown.

A good example is this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb324497%28VS.85%29.aspx. I cannot add Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback to my references. I read about MediaElement, too, however, it drove me to the same path.

I don't know, either, if the C# video players will use the codecs that are installed on the user system. I don't know what to do now.

Comment: What error are you seeing when you add the DirectX library. Do you have the DirectX SDK installed?

Answer (score 0):

Check your project properties.  Make sure you're targeting the full .Net Framework, not one of the Client Profiles.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the WPF controls, they are easier.

http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=73040

So something like:

```
  <MediaElement Source="myMedia.wmv" Width="320"   
     Height="240" LoadedBehavior="Manual" />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163455.aspx